# Notify and NotifyAll affecting threads in blocked state only

Tags: java, multithreading

[image]

My understanding is when we call object.notify (one thread) and object.notifyAll (all threads),  threads in the blocked state are being notified.

Runnable state threads are not getting any notification.

Comment: Suggest what? `notify` **means** "unblock". There are no actual messages involved; the waiting thread doesn't get notified of any reified event.

Comment: Runnable threads will be executed as soon as the processor can schedule them.  Why would you want to notify them?

Comment: Well, if you want all your set of threads to run exactly as many times as they are signaled, even if some are currently running, give each thread a semaphore to wait on. When you want to signal that another run is required from all the threads, signal all the semaphores.

Answer (score 2):

> threads in the blocked state are being notified.

Sort of.  `notify` wakes up threads that are in a [WAITING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING) state.

The notification then put's them into a [BLOCKED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED) state until they can acquire the object monitor they were waiting on.  Objects that are already BLOCKED on the initial `synchronized` call are unaffected.

RUNNABLE threads won't be notified because they are not WAITING on the monitor.